# Emacs-like Meta (Option/Alt) key functionality in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, osx-lion

I'd like to have word-forward/backward functionality with M-f and M-b plus all the other convenient shortcuts. Is this possible?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `OS X` here. Please give an example what you want to accomplish. PS: I dont use mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, put this in your `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` (create it if it doesn't exists), and put the following:

```
{
"~f"        = "moveWordForward:";               /* M-f Move forward word */
"~b"        = "moveWordBackward:";              /* M-b Move backward word */
"~<"        = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";     /* M-< Move to beginning of document */
"~>"        = "moveToEndOfDocument:";           /* M-> Move to end of document */
}
```

See [here](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) if you want the full reference of the OS X keyboard characters. And [here](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Emacs%20Opt%20Bindings.dict) if you want more emacs keybindings in OS X.